# Elements behave weirdly when I use "scrollIntoView" function with "pointer-events: none"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a simple countdown application with HTML CSS and JS. I have three number selectors for hours, minutes and seconds. And a button to start countdown. And when countdown starts, I animate numbers. I wanted to disable scrolling on number selectors after countdown starts to prevent messing animations. So when user clicks the button, I set `pointer-events: none` to number selectors and start the animations.

The problem is: when I don't set `pointer-events: none`, everything works just fine. But when I do, animations get messy and elements behave so weirdly. Like elements which aren't supposed to animate, start to animate. And drop-shadows appear where they aren't supposed to appear.

[This is what it's supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JGAn.png)

[And this is when I set `pointer-events: none` and things get messy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzoEx.png)

Here is my button handler function:

```
    function btnHandler() {
    const rect = [div1.getBoundingClientRect(), div2.getBoundingClientRect(), div3.getBoundingClientRect()], centerCell = [];
    centerCell[0] = document.elementFromPoint((rect[0].left + div1.offsetWidth / 2), (rect[0].top + div1.offsetHeight / 2));
    centerCell[1] = document.elementFromPoint((rect[1].left + div2.offsetWidth / 2), (rect[1].top + div2.offsetHeight / 2));
    centerCell[2] = document.elementFromPoint((rect[2].left + div3.offsetWidth / 2), (rect[2].top + div3.offsetHeight / 2));
    console.log([centerCell[0].innerText, centerCell[1].innerText, centerCell[2].innerText]);
    div1.style.pointerEvents = "none", div2.style.pointerEvents = "none", div3.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    var i = (parseInt(centerCell[0].innerText) - 1), j = (parseInt(centerCell[1].innerText) - 1), k = (parseInt(centerCell[2].innerText) - 1);
    innerInner[2][k].scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "center", inline: "center" });
    k--;
    var interval3 = setInterval(() => {
        innerInner[2][k].scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "center", inline: "center" });
        k--;
        if (k < 0) {
            k = 59;
            innerInner[1][j].scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "center", inline: "center" });
            j--;
            var interval2 = setInterval(() => {
                innerInner[1][j].scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "center", inline: "center" });
                j--;
                if (j < 0) {
                    j = 59;
                    innerInner[0][i].scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "center", inline: "center" });
                    i--;
                    var interval1 = setInterval(() => {
                        innerInner[0][i].scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "center", inline: "center" });
                        i--;
                        if (i < 0) {
                            clearInterval(interval1);
                            clearInterval(interval2);
                            clearInterval(interval3);
                        }
                    }, 3600000);
                }
            }, 60000);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

As you can see, I am using `scrollIntoView()` method and I think using this method with `pointer-events: none` causes the problem. Can you help?

Comment: There is no way to determine your issue, with the code you have provided. `innerInner` is undefined and we can't see your Events.

Comment: `scrollIntoView` has no relation with `pointer-events`.  
However `document.elementFromPoint` does have a strong relation with it: if your element can't be touched by a pointer, it can't be found by this method.

Comment: @StackSlave `innerInner` is basically a 2D array which contains the child divs inside number selectors. Three number selectors each have 59 child divs. I use them to scroll-snap alignment and animations.

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you for helpful information. Can you suggest a way to handle that?

Comment: Would be easier to understand your problem and find a workaround with a working example, but I can't even promise I'd have the time to look at it sorry. But first, it's unclear why you even use that method to determine which element to show, you'd probabbly be better using a more state-aware machine.